# How to get a specific configuration in youtube-dl?

Tags: debian, python, youtube-dl

I want to make the following as my best parameter to youtube-dl to consider while downloading a media file.

```
/media/$ youtube-dl -c -f youtube-dl 'bestvideo[height<=720]+bestaudio/best[height<=720 VideoID
```

I made a config file according to https://github.com/ytdl-org/youtube-dl#configuration, but it's currently empty.

I am trying to figure out what to write in the config file.

```
$ cat ~/.config/youtube-dl/config
$ youtube-dl --version
2019.09.28
```

Using Debian testing (all updated).

Comment: "You can configure youtube-dl by placing **any supported command line option** to a configuration file"

Comment: Your first command seems to be incomplete.

Comment: my question was complete, it just had an extra -f which I removed. @GAD3R shared with me the answer as below :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `~/.config/youtube-dl/config` should be:

```
-f bestvideo[height<=720]+bestaudio/best[height<=720]
```

usage: `youtube-dl url`

`youtube-dl` will download the best audio and the best audio separately then it will be merged.

You can use the `-k` option to keep the downloaded files (audio + video).